# Swift 3 numberOfRows table view function error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm currently having an issue with trying to use a value as the return for the `numberOfRows` function for my table view. In my `viewDidLoad` I have the code below and it prints the value that I need, however when i try to return the same variable it says found nil when unwrapping value. Any suggestions?

```
let prevOrderRef = ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID!).child("Previous Orders")

    prevOrderRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let dict = PreviousOrders(snapshot: snapshot)
        self.prevOrderCount = dict.prevOrdersDict?.count
        print(self.prevOrderCount!)

    })
```

UPDATE:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:            Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.currentOrderTblView {

        return 1
    } else {

        let prevOrderRef = ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID!).child("Previous Orders")

        prevOrderRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


            let dict = PreviousOrders(snapshot: snapshot)
            self.prevOrderCount = dict.prevOrdersDict?.count
            print(self.prevOrderCount!)



        })

        return 2
    }


}
```

I have moved the firebase database data observe inside the numberOfRows.
This prints the value needed but I am still unable to use it as the return.

Comment: give the code that crashes

Comment: @Saranjith

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.currentOrderTblView {
            
            return 1
        } else {
            
            
            return self.prevOrderCount!
        }
        
        
    }

Comment: this is what crashes

Comment: Try to debug your code, by adding tow breakpoints, one on `self.prevOrderCount = dict.prevOrdersDict?.count` line and `return self.prevOrderCount!` and check which one has been executed first

Comment: @AhmadF 

I've done that now and the return self.prevOrderCount! is the line that got highlighted in green.

Comment: **NEVER EVER** execute asynchonous code in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ! from return statement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{ 
  if tableView == self.currentOrderTblView 
  { 
   return 1 
  } 
  else
  { 
   return self.prevOrderCount
  }
}
```

declare that variabe as

```
 var prevOrderCount: Int!
```

Also initialize it in viewDidLoad as

```
  self.prevOrderCount=0 // 0 or anything you wanted as default
```

These optionals are assumed to contain a value. Therefore whenever you access it will implicitly unwrapped optional, it will automatically be force unwrapped for you. If it doesn’t contain a value, it will crash.

**Make sure you have Assigned a value**

Comment: That gives me an error forcing me to unwrap it unfortunately.

Comment: I still get the same "found nil while unwrapping an optional value" error :/

Comment: make sure it is not nil.. init it anywhere. see the edit

Comment: This is just returning the value I initialise it with in viewDidLoad (1).

Comment: it is because you're not modifying the value anywhere in code.. if you wanted to modify put like  **self.prevOrderCount=15**

Comment: Reload the table view when all operations where over

Comment: I am modifying the value within the code. check the code written under the UPDATE part of my post

Comment: dont use this inside numberOfRaws func.. put it in fuction and call from viewdidload

Comment: Thank You!!! It's working now! Reloading the table view is what did it!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're trying to access remote database which is most likely an async call, so you just don't have a value at the moment `numberOfRowsInsection` is being hit.

**EDIT**

The simplest way is using `didSet` for `self.prevOrderDict`. That way you will know exactly when the value is assigned to the Dict.

Initially you can check if `self.prevOrderDict != nil` and if so use count as return value, else return 0. This will give you an empty table. Once `didSet` is hit you can use `tableView.reloadData()`.

```
var prevOrderDict = [] {
     didSet {
     tableView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if self.prevOrderDict != nil {
          return self.prevOrderDict.count 
     } else {
          return 0 
     }
```

Comment: Any Suggestions then?